# Счетчик в многопоточном приложении

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

Как добавить счетчик в многопоточное приложение?

```
from lxml import html
import time,random,requests,os
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
from colorama import init,Fore,Back,Style
init()

# определяем текущий каталог и печатаем
a = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d %H-%M")
path = a
os.mkdir(path)
class MyThread(Thread):
    """
    A threading example
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        amount = random.randint(15, 30)
        time.sleep(amount)
        msg = "%s is running" % self.name
        print(msg)



def random_e():
    str = []
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
    num = 6
    for k in range(1, num+1):
        str.append(random.choice(chars))
    str = "".join(str)
    return str
start_time = datetime.now()
def main():
    with open("log.txt", "r") as file:
        old = file.read().split('\n')
    while True:

        URL = 'http://' + 'www.prnt.sc/' + random_e()
        if URL not in old:
            with open("log.txt","a") as file:
                file.write(URL+'\n')
            page = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            parsed_body = html.document_fromstring(page.text)
            image = parsed_body.xpath('//img[@class="no-click screenshot-image"]/@src')
            try:

                if image[0]:
                    if image[0]=='//st.prntscr.com/2018/10/13/2048/img/0_173a7b_211be8ff.png':
                        print(Fore.RED+ 'Пустое изображение\n')
                        print(Fore.WHITE+'-----------------------------------------------\n')
                        continue
                    else:
                        #----------------------------------------------------------------------------Вот сюда счетсчик
                        print(Fore.BLUE + URL+'\n')
                        print(Fore.BLUE+image[0]+'\n')
                        print(Fore.WHITE+'-----------------------------------------------\n')
                    response = requests.get(image[0])
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                            with open(path+"/"+random_e()+".jpg", 'wb') as f:
                                f.write(response.content)


            except Exception:
                continue
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=main)
    t2 = Thread(target=main)
    t3 = Thread(target=main)
    t4 = Thread(target=main)
    t5 = Thread(target=main)
    t6 = Thread(target=main)
    t7 = Thread(target=main)
    t8 = Thread(target=main)
    t9 = Thread(target=main)
    t10 = Thread(target=main)
    t11 = Thread(target=main)
    t12 = Thread(target=main)
    t13 = Thread(target=main)
    t14 = Thread(target=main)
    t15 = Thread(target=main)
    t16 = Thread(target=main)
    t17 = Thread(target=main)
    t18 = Thread(target=main)
    t19 = Thread(target=main)
    t20 = Thread(target=main)
    t21 = Thread(target=main)
    t22 = Thread(target=main)
    t23 = Thread(target=main)
    t24 = Thread(target=main)
    t25 = Thread(target=main)
    t26 = Thread(target=main)
    t27 = Thread(target=main)
    t28 = Thread(target=main)
    t29 = Thread(target=main)
    t30 = Thread(target=main)

    # start threads
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t5.start()
    t6.start()
    t7.start()
    t8.start()
    t9.start()
    t10.start()
    t11.start()
    t12.start()
    t13.start()
    t14.start()
    t15.start()
    t16.start()
    t17.start()
    t18.start()
    t19.start()
    t20.start()
    t21.start()
    t22.start()
    t23.start()
    t24.start()
    t25.start()
    t26.start()
    t27.start()
    t28.start()
    t29.start()
    t30.start()
```

Comment: И с чем именно у вас проблемы?

Comment: Счетчик постоянно перезаписывается и счет идет непоследовательно

Comment: Что должен сделать код и что должен делать счётчик?

Answer (score 1):

Операция инкремента (`counter += 1`) не является потокобезопасной в python. В процессе выполнения программы возникают состояния гонки из-за которых счетчик не будет равен количеству инкрементов в конце выполнения.

Например:

```
import threading


counter = 0


def worker():
    global counter
    for _ in range(1000000):
        counter += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker) for _ in range(10)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print(counter)
```

При повторных запусках этого кода счетчик принимает различные значения в конце выполнения программы:

```
$ python3 th-counter.py
4133263
$ /tmp python3 th-counter.py
3174004
```

Для того, чтобы избежать состояния гонки применяются различные примитивы синхронизации, которые не позволяют нескольким потокам выполнть некоторую критическую часть кода одновременно.
Перепишем с использованием `threading.Lock`:

```
import time
import threading


counter = 0
lock = threading.Lock()


def worker():
    global counter
    for _ in range(1000000):
        with lock:
            counter += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker) for _ in range(10)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print(counter)
```

Эта версия всегда возвращает `10000000`